# All Russian letters change to "????" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding

Every time I save and run a file through VSCode, all Russian letters change to "????".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szDZu.jpg)

Comment: pls. check the configuration. What's the value of `files.encoding`?

Comment: "files.encoding": "utf8",<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>

Answer (score 5):

According to the status bar you've opened the file as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That's the default ANSI codepage for Windows OS in Western Europe and it cannot store Cyrillic characters at all.

[image]

I suggest you take a minute to set a proper default configuration for these two directives:

```
// The default character set encoding to use when reading and writing files. This setting can be configured per language too.
"files.encoding": "utf8",

// When enabled, will attempt to guess the character set encoding when opening files. This setting can be configured per language too.
"files.autoGuessEncoding": false,
```

Pick a different encoding if you aren't using UTF-8 in a general basis. You may also enable `files.autoGuessEncoding` if you typically mix different encodings, but be aware that it isn't magic (there's no reliable way to detect text encoding programmatically, not at least in a simple tool like a text editor).

These directives can also be set in a per-project basis and even in a per type file basis. Additionally, current file can entirely bypass prior settings; the simplest way is to click on the encoding name in the status bar and pick a command:

- *Reopen with Encoding* renders the file with a different encoding. It doesn't alter the file.
- *Save with Encoding* converts the file to another encoding. It does modify the file thus you need to ensure that source encoding is correct.

Comment: I have and it's worth it. "files.encoding": "utf8", <head> <meta charset = "utf-8"> </ head>

Comment: "files.autoGuessEncoding": true

Comment: @JohnShevchenko Sorry, I'm not sure of what you want to tell me. I understand the file is meant to be UTF-8. Is it actually UTF-8 and you need help to instruct VSCode to open it as such? Or it's using some other encoding and you need to convert it to UTF-8? I've edited my answer anyway to explain both options. (As about `files.autoGuessEncoding`, I strongly suggest you *disable* it unless you have a good reason.)

Comment: "Reopen with Encoding renders the file with a different encoding. It doesn't alter the file."
That helped. Now I understand how it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank You much!